# Xcode 7.2 support 3D Touch in Simulator?

Tags: xcode

I've been out of the country for a while and trying to get caught up with everything. I didn't see it anywhere thought I'd ask here before I went to the dev forums. When I left the simulator didn't support hot keys or any way to test a 3D Touch short press and long press. Is this now supported or do you still need a capable device?

Answer (score 1):

Right now Apple haven't done the 3D touch for the iPhone Simulator yet, but on the Apple Watch Simulator it is fine. If you want to test for the 3D touch feature of your app, you need a capable iPhone to do it. Right now if you go to the Hardware menu, then there are a force touch pressure menu. It is disabled. That is the 3D touch feature that Apple might implement.